# guitar amp plays back vibrating sound after playing two consecutive notes on lead/od/metal profiles

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I'm new to guitars. Here's an audio recording where I'm playing two notes twice. First time I mute in between them and it produces what I would expect it to. Then I play them consecutively and they sound like they're vibrating.

It's a NUX Mighty 20BT amp and it only happens on profiles other than the acoustic. It also sounds  fine on its own.

https://sndup.net/8sn5/d

Is this normal? I can reproduce it on two guitars.

```
|-----------------
|-----------------
|-----------11----
|---14------------
|-----------------
|-----------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds normal to me - just an example of a prominent [beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) effect, exaggerated by the distortion:

> when the two tones are close in pitch but not identical, the
>   difference in frequency generates the beating. The volume varies like
>   in a tremolo as the sounds alternately interfere constructively and
>   destructively.

If you don't want the gap in between the notes and you also don't want the beating, you need to get good at muting the first note just at the same time as you play the second. This is one of the main skills in playing distorted electric guitar.

Comment: 'Tremolo' as *not* defined by Leo...